# pgmagick on Mac OS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, installation, pgmagick

I try to install pgmagick on my MacOS Mojave (10.14.6). On the https://pypi.org/project/pgmagick/ there is a guide for installing on MacOS:
1) When I try the first method ($brew install pgmagick --with-python3) I'm getting an error: 'Error: invalid option: --with-python3'. When I try $brew install pgmagick-python3 I have an issue: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga6Ru.png)
2) When I try the second method ($ brew install graphicsmagick $ brew install boost-python3 $ pip install pgmagick) I'm getting the following issue (on the command $ pip install pgmagick):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqJLD.png)

Could you help me?

Comment: I think it's best to install python3 on homebrew and make it the [system default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704364/make-python3-as-my-default-python-on-mac) and then just use `brew install pgmagick`.

Comment: Maybe have a read of my comments here... https://stackoverflow.com/q/57803621/2836621

Comment: @trojanfoe, I tried the method that you suggest. However, when I try to import the module, the following error occurs "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pgmagick' ".

Comment: Are you certain you are running homebrew python3?

Comment: @trojanfoe, yes